# Converting file type using subprocess.run in Python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, file-conversion

I am attempting to convert a bulk lot of files from one type to another. I need to use a specific command to do so, but am having trouble getting subprocess.run to work. It just seems to hang when I run the script, so I'm obviously missing something, but can't figure out what.

The code I have so far is below.

```
import pathlib
import subprocess
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='Bulk Convert',
    description='Bulk convert from .raw to .es')

parser.add_argument('source')
parser.add_argument('target')           
args = parser.parse_args()


source_path = pathlib.Path(args.source)
target_path = pathlib.Path(args.target)

print(f"Converting all files in {source_path} to {target_path}")

files = [x for x in source_path.glob('**/*') if x.is_file() and str(x).endswith(".raw")]

for file in files:
    file_path =  target_path / f"{file.stem}.es"
    cmd = ["/home/release/evt3_to_es", str(source_path), str(file_path)]
    print(f"Processing {file_path}")
    subprocess.run(cmd)
```

The script I run to convert single files at a time sits in ./evt3_to_es, which converts .raw to .es files.

From the command line, I run
python3 convert.py ~/file/path/of/bulk/files ~/output/of/bulk/conversion